Confd clispec <params> does not accept "multi" attribute
From confd clicpec docs+guide we can find that:
/clispec/$MODE/cmd/params

It can accept 4 attributes, want to post a notice about "multi" one, mentioning 'mode' one as well.

mode (list|choice) This is an optional attribute. If it is "choice" then at least "min" and
at most "max" params must be given by the user. 
If it is "list" then all nonoptional parameters must be given the command in the order they appear in the list.

multi (xs:boolean) 
This optional attribute controls if each parameters should be allowed to be entered more than once. 
If set to "true" then each parameter may occur multiple times. The default is "false".

However adding multi attribute to <params> results into "Invalid entity: multi" error.

It is not mentioned in docs, that if 'multi' is added while "mode" attribute is not set, or "mode" is "list", then you will end up with an error:
Invalid entity: multi
To fix it need to explicitly set mode="choice"
